# How to overcome the limit of hyperlinks in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a list of links in more than 100000 cells.

[image: Example]

I have to give hyperlinks to all of them but in Excel there is a limit of [65530](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) hyperlinks per worksheet.

How can I overcome the limit or how can I merge cells with equal values using VBA?

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A1")
    Dim hText As Variant

    Do Until IsEmpty(myRange)

        hText = Application.VLookup(myRange.Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B"), 2, False)

        If IsError(hText) Then
            hText = ""
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:="http://" + hText, TextToDisplay:=myRange.Text
            hText = ""
        End If

        Set myRange = myRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't need open multiple files at once, use a button with dynamic location (via worksheet selection change) to open the file (store the actual path on another column).

Comment: you can use one hyperlink for range of contiguous cells

Comment: @Slai Can you help me to do this using macros?

Comment: Can you post the code that you currently have from your previous question so I can get the ranges and Sheet names right. Also, are the key-value pairs in the same order as the repeated values?

Comment: @Slai add code to the question... It adds one link for one cell.  On Sheet2 I have key->value parts like: `AAAAA.jpg BBBBB.jpg CCCCC.jpg in column A` and `www.111.com www.222.com www.333.com in column B`
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just regular copy paste should work, but I can update the example (not tested) if it doesn't

```
Sub AddHyperlinks() 

    Dim rng As Range, rngFrom As Range, values, r
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set rngFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

    rng.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Delete   ' remove all previous Hyperlinks

    While rng(1) > ""

        ' resize the range to the same values
        While rng(rng.Rows.Count + 1) = rng(1)
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1)
        Wend

        r = Application.Match(rng(1), rngFrom, 0)    
        If Not IsError(r) Then
            values = rng.Value2    ' save the values 
            rngFrom(r, 2).Copy rng ' copy from the cell next to the match
            rng.Value2 = values    ' restore the values (not sure if it removes the links) 
        End If

        Set rng = rng(rng.Rows.Count + 1) ' move to the next cell below
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much... everything seems to be works as expected. Can I ask you if some problem will appear

Comment: I am a bit surprised that it works without any problems because I was mostly guessing and I could not test it. If it's problem related to my answer or this question, sure.

Comment: I've got some problem, if i have free cells in the column, the script is interrupting. How can i fix it?

Comment: @ZeroEight I guess you can replace the `While rng(1) > ""` with something like `While rng.Row <= rng.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as mentioned by @Rory:
Use the HYPERLINK function in your cell to emulate a hyperlink via a formula.

```
=HYPERLINK(url, displaytext)
```

This effectively bypasses the built-in Excel limit on "hard-coded" hyperlinks. Just tested this out after I hit the infamous error 1004:

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

when trying to create 100k+ hyperlinks in a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the URL in (eg) colA then something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim URL
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub '<< only reacting if cell in URL column is right-clicked
    URL = Target.Value
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
End Sub
```

Alternatively use the `Before_DoubleClick` event

It does mean you can't use a "friendly" link text such as "click here", but you could likely manage that if you store the URL text at a fixed offset and then read that instead of Target.Value

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem and I know that I shouldn't have more than around 120000 rows that need hyperlinking so modified some code I found in another thread to this

```
Sub hyperlink2()
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cell2 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set rng = Range("X2:X60000")


For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell <> "" Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell, Cell.Value
Next

Set Rng2 = Range("X60001:X120000")
For Each Cell2 In Rng2
    If Cell2 <> "" Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell2, Cell2.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Hope that helps someone else who stumbles upon this via google (like I did) looking for a workable solution...

Answer (score -1):

The 255 character limit applies to the limit of character that can be put in one cell's formula. A common approach to this is by splitting the link into multiple cells and using a formula to combine them.

```
=HYPERLINK(A1&A2,"Click Here")
```

Comment: Not a character limit. There is a limit for number of hyperlinks per worksheet https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: AFAIK, that limit of 65536 doesn't apply when using the HYPERLINK formula though.