# link column doesn't extend to end of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I'm running a code on a dataframe which has a link column where it has a link to a page in it.
based on some trial and error I realized that the result is fine untill I reach this part of the code:

```
df1 = df[df['operator'] == 'test']
df1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df1[phone_col] = df1['new_phone']
df.to_excel(f'step2_1.xlsx', index=False)
```

when I open the step2_1.xlsx, the link column goes only to index of 65531 and then after that its blank like the picture below.
[image]
how can i fix it? is it related to a setting for vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a built in hyperlink limit of 65530.

[Source 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-hyperlinks-using-macro-fails-to-load-more/52df0cd7-b356-46bd-8ad0-e8fe3ef8d426), [Source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/llzzp4/runtime_error_1004_adding_hyperlink/), [Source 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:%7E:text=Hyperlinks%20in%20a,65%2C530).

You can bypass this limit by [using the `HYPERLINK` function of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419995/4458369).

So as an example:

```py
(pd.DataFrame([['test', '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")']]*65600, columns = ['Name', 'Link'])
 .to_excel(f'step2_1.xlsx', index=False))
```

[image]

### EDIT

This shows how to convert the current string in your column to the Excel hyperlink formula easily:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['test', 'https://www.google.com/']]*10, columns = ['Name', 'Link'])
df['Link'] = df.Link.apply(lambda x: f'=HYPERLINK("{x}")')
```

Output:

```
    Name    Link
0   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
1   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
2   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
3   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
4   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
5   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
6   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
7   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
8   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
9   test    =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: So how can I change the result from hyperlink to string before writing to excel?

Comment: The hyperlink is a string in Pandas. Just use a lambda function to add the Excel formula around your hyperlink string. See edit